# How can I limit the text to a div's width?

Tags: html, css, text, width

I am trying to limit text to a `div`'s width and can not get it to work.

Where it says TESTE3 I want the text not to go over the edge of the red div. Can anyone help me please?
[Image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1qa9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you give us example code using either the built in code editor, or jsfiddle.

There are two ways however to solve your problem.

You can either go for `overflow:hidden;` as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/L62w981g/

Or you can have the text flow over to the next line using `word-break` or `white-space` as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/L62w981g/1/

Here is the code for the overflow fix:

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
  height:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:350px;
}
```

```html
<div>
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkthistextishidden
</div>
```

Here is the code for the white-space fix:

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
  height:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:350px;
  word-break:break-all;
  white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkthistextishidden
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The overflow did the trick. I really didn't want to use more than one line in this case

Comment: yeah, I can only do that in a couple minutes I don't really know why

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS:

```
word-break: break-all;
```